# can users install browser add ons without admin privileges?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-addons, administrator, privileges

We have a Windows 7 SOE, and users do not have administrator privileges.

Is it possible for users to install Internet Explorer add-ons without administrator privileges?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the GUI requests admin, because it tries to register the ActiveX COM class globally. However, there's no reason I know of why it couldn't be registered to the per-user classes registry, which is writable without admin.

Comment: I think it depends on the add-n & the policies applied to the computer/user

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, **yes**.

Regardless, I would strongly advise you make some changes using the ***Local Group Policy Editor***. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `gpedit.msc`.

- Navigate to: `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer` then edit:

> Automatically activate newly installed add-ons to **Disabled**
>
> Do not allow users to enable or disable add-ons to **Enabled**

- Navigate to: `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Advance Page` then edit:

> Do not allow resetting IE settings to **Enabled**
>
> Allow third-party browser extensions to **Disabled**

That should lock down IE in regards to add-ons. More information can be found at the [source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn454941.aspx).

Hope this helps!